# Copying file into unknown directory in WinBatch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I am writing my own Half-Frontend Console App. I have a problem with the `XCOPY` command.
I want to copy `PBOOT.PBP` file into folder

```
ux0_pspemu_temp_game_PSP_GAME_!randomletters&numbers!
```

Example:

```
xcopy %CD%\data\easyinstaller\ARK\PBOOT.PBP %CD%\Delete_me\ux0_pspemu_temp_game_PSP_GAME_!randomletters&numbers!
```

In this case the folder name is: 
`ux0_pspemu_temp_game_PSP_GAME_NPEG00024`

But in other cases the name will differ - e.g.  `ux0_pspemu_temp_game_PSP_GAME_NPUH99313`.

Comment: `&` is a special character in batch. Try changing the variable name to something like `!random_letters_and_numbers!` instead.

Comment: @SomethingDark No, for example, this folder have this name ux0_pspemu_temp_game_PSP_GAME_NPEG00024, but other users this folder will have the name e.g.  ux0_pspemu_temp_game_PSP_GAME_NPUH99313. (I'm bad in English)

Comment: If there's only one ux0_pspemu[...] directory, you can probably just replace that string of random letters and numbers with a `*` in your xcopy command.

Comment: As you are not using any of the included `XCopy` options, _(BTW XCopy was deprecated in favour of RoboCopy pre Vista)_, there doesn't appear to be any reason to use it over the standard `Copy` command. Also as you cannot be certain of the location of the current directory enclose both the source and destination in double quotes, `Copy "%CD%\data\easyinstaller\ARK\PBOOT.PBP" "%CD%\Delete_me\ux0_pspemu_temp_game_PSP_GAME_!alphanumericstring!"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably just determine the name of the directory first, possibly setting it as a variable for easy re-use:

```bat
SET "DESTDIR="
FOR /D %%A IN ("%CD%\Delete_me\ux0_pspemu_temp_game_PSP_GAME_NP*") DO SET "DESTDIR=%%A"
IF NOT DEFINED DESTDIR EXIT/B
COPY /Y "%CD%\data\easyinstaller\ARK\PBOOT.PBP" "%DESTDIR%"
```